# Is it okay to always leave a database connection open?

Tags: database

I'm working on a single-user desktop database application sort of thing in my spare time, and I'm always unsure about the design choices I'm making. Right now, as it stands, whenever the user wants to interact with the database (which is a local SQLite database, so generally only one user ever sees it at once), the application creates a new connection, does whatever it needs to do, and then closes the connection. Thereforee, over the course of one execution of the application, lots of connections are created and disposed of.

Is this generally the "best" way to go about it, or should the application open the connection at startup and only close it when the application exits? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each method?

Comment: Search on Stackoverflow.com. This question has been asked repeatedly there.

Comment: @JeffO And each question asked seems to have different, often slightly (or totally) disagreeing answers.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would say it's fine in this case, since there will only ever be one user and the database is hosted on the same machine (more likely in the same memory space, as I think SQLite just loads as a DLL with the main application) as the application. Constantly opening and closing the connection is unnecessary.

One possible exception might be if you need to have multiple threads of your application accessing the database at the same time. Then you could either force them to wait and share a single connection object, *OR* you could try to create new connections for the different threads. I have never actually tried this in SQLite. This is one situation where closing the main connection and opening/closing multiple connections might be better for a desktop app.

For web applications, or client/server desktop apps, I'd suggest against leaving connections open.

Comment: You might be the first person who answered to have actually read the question in full.

Comment: @Andrew: You sure it's not just the first answer to agree with your pre-existing viewpoint?  Utilizing the connection pool will allow your application to re-use one single connection that is left open, but without architecting your application around that decision. You can still write code that acquires and releases the connection resource only as needed.

Comment: @qes: SQLite doesn't support connection pooling, so it's not relevant.

Comment: @Andrew Arnold This really is a localized case specific to SQLite; keep that in mind going forward. In one hand you state you are using SQLite but appear to want to know the route to take form a generalized stance; then on the other hand you seem to want to know the best implementation within SQLite. Different animals.

Comment: @Aaron - I want to know the best implementation with SQLite. I guess I'm still not terribly good at expressing my questions here.

Comment: @Andrew Arnold Fair enough. As you pointed out SQLite has no connection pooling support out of the box; in addition cached data is connection related so closing/opening a connection will actually hinder performance.

Comment: [Can multiple applications or multiple instances of the same application access a single database file at the same time?](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Answer (score 11):

Typically the connection is closed after use; freeing it back into the pool of available connections. If there are a high number of transactions taking place on a single client it makes sense to leverage a single connection instead of creating multiple connections only to immediately close them.

It is somewhat circumstantial however the typical best practice is to close it after use so that it becomes available within the pool again.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a connection pool. Typically a connection pool keeps the connections open, and the application retrieves/returns connections from/to the pool. Connections could be held open for months or years. And a connection pool can also be used to throttle database access and improve throughput. Opening 1000 connections is going to choke the database and the application, but if only 5 connections are available each transaction will complete quickly and the application will have a decent throughput. Pool sizes are app dependent and require tuning

Comment: Connection pools not really relevant as OP's talking about a single use local SQLite database.

Comment: @gnuchu The OP is asking about best practices. Withholding information applicable to the situation both now and in the future when replying to those types of questions simply because the OP didn't explicitly call it out is unfair to the OP. If providing additional information to the OP is frowned upon; so be it...I personally appreciate when others expand on my question and touch on things which I may not have previously been aware of.

Comment: @gnuchu: it is absolutely relevant.  Using a connection pool gains the performance of leaving a connection open while allowing the code to be structured to acquire and release resources for the minimal amount needed.

Comment: @qes I guess it's a point of view thing. OP was asking about a standalone SQLite database. IMO if we answer with all the information in the world about connecting to databases it just becomes noise.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine you have 1000 users accessing your application at the same time. That would means 1000 open connections. Eventually you could run out of connections. So let each user open a connection, use it, and then close it so that connection is free for others to use.

**Further Clarification**

Imagine him having multiple modules that would simultaneous need the same connection? Image simultaneously running controls needing the connection. What is he going to do? Have a global connection object? Use a Singleton Pattern? Tell me if I am wrong

Comment: No, it's a personal desktop application. Only one user ever accesses the database. I should have made that more clear.

Comment: then I would say its just not good design. Might incur problems in the future

Comment: it is in fact a good design for a desktop application. In fact it's the norm for such applications, and has been for decades. It works, it's reliable, and it performs better than reopening the connection all the time.

Comment: @jwenting: Actually there's very little (almost zero) performance difference between the two.  Because of this it's better to go with practices that are both more common and easier to translate to larger multi-user applications.

Comment: @jwenting @Andrew Arnold : imagine him having multiple modules that would simultaneous need the same connection? Image simultaneously running controls needing the connection. What is he going to do? Have a global connection object? Use a Singleton Pattern? Tell me if I am wrong

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh: He says it's a local SQLite database for a desktop application, so it will only have a single user at a time.

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh: You're point about multiple modules needing to connect at the same point is valid, you might want to clarify that in your answer (otherwise, people who downvoted won't be able to change their downvote - if they wanted to - unless the answer itself changes).

Comment: @Imran: that's why you have things like connection pooling, or centralised access to the database. There's typically a database access module that channels database requests for all other modules. To the other modules, the database doesn't exist, only the database access module does. That one may have multiple connections, a single shared connection, or connect only on demand, depending on application needs.

Answer (score 2):

Connection pooling *should* make this a moot point.  The pool should keep a connection around and open for you to reuse.  This should allow you to follow the generally best practice of using resources for the shortest reasonable amount but without sacrificing performance.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with database connection my policy is that in depends on what you need to do. For example, if your are loading a lot of realted critical data  my advice would be to encapsulate all your operations in one transaction and with one conection that should be close after the transaction is commited.

Now, if you need to do lots of queries retrieving data, opening and closing a connection for each query could be quite expensive so, leaving a connection open is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I just started asking myself this same question. Like you, it's just a single app and I'm not worried about running out of connections.

I did however run into a potential issue with leaving the database open though: transactions. If you do a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and there's an error or something else happens where your code doesn't hit a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, then you leave that transaction open.

So it might be better to close it solely for the purpose of ensuring everything is restored after work is done to the database.

I really don't know how much overhead there is in opening and closing the database though. I'd love to hear some other people's thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

Opening new connection is expensive. 
Therefore, the best way to use a connection is to mark it as idle after finishing a transaction. The connection will then be returned to a pool of idle connections.

When application requests a connection, the code must check the pool of idle {free} connection and return one. If there is no idle connection in the pool then a new connection should be used. When a connection is provided to a service or to an entity, the connection must be marked 'active'; so that the connection is not provided to any subsequent request.

When the connection is not closed, you must handle the connection properly regarding commit, rollback etc.

Check your language or framework. Most of the frameworks already maintain a container of idle connections; and therefore, you do not need to worry about it. 
Some of the languages also provide this functionality out of the box. For example Golang core package type sql.DB maintains a pool of idle connections, capable of being used concurrently, so you do not need to worry about closing the connection.