# Php resource freeing

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

My client has their web hosting account on a shared server and their account has been suspended because is was "causing critical server overload". I have looked at the code and it is functionally programmed php that uses a lot of database queries. I have looked through and most of them are "SELECT *". This database has tables with a 10 or more rows and more than 1000 records.

I was wondering if the cause could be all the sql queries not being freed up, but I'm not sure when "script execution" finishes. Is it after the function has finished execution, or the whole page has been rendered? Could it be the size of the tables (structure or records)? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Was the overload because of disk, cpu, or memory?

Comment: The hosting company should tell you what they mean exactly by "causing critical server overload"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the kind of package your client was on, what type of script custom coded or a standard script like wordpress.

**Causing critical server overload** - Could be a multitude of things:

**High Memory usage:** The script is not using a singleton model or its assigning huge amounts of data to arrays, variables or including lots of files. basically bad design & code smell.

**High CPU:** Insanely long scripts, Long iterated loops with complex calculations in between or infinite loops (sockets) ect on each page view.

**High Network Traffic:** Screen Scappers like a crawler thats requesting high amounts of traffic from other site or basically scripts that grab external content ALOT, or something like a torrent tracker.

**High Disk usage:** Constantly bombarding the servers IO stack (Writing and reading to the disk constantly)

A script with lots of database query's could fall into: High Disk usage (reading)+High Memory usage (iterating the result)+High CPU (doing stuff with the result))

You should use a tool to performance profile the script locally: [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) or [PQP](http://particletree.com/features/php-quick-profiler/), and find out whats really happening.

If your client is serious about there site then they should invest in a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are closing your SQL connections properly. If you are doing alot of queries at once it might be more efficient to leave the connection open for longer periods. Or if you are not closing them after each query maybe try doing this. I must say 10 tables is not a lot and would it would suprise me that this is overloading the shared server.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone How many queries per script? If there are alot of them this is probably good. If not try closing your connection after every query to see if that helps. Leaving unused connections open for long periods of time will use up a lot of resources on the host machine.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474646/is-it-okay-to-always-leave-a-database-connection-open)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone note that creating an index of your tables will also improve performance

Comment: only mysql_pconnect connections stay open after script finnishes, from the mysql_connect manual `The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close(). `